# angular-datetime-picker not work in modal

Tags: angularjs

I inject a module call angular-datetime-picker into my Angular app. 
This module is easy to use, as I only need to include js and css code in my index.html, then I can put

```
<input ng-model="$parent.date5" datetime-picker date-format="dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm" />
```

It working fine, but not in my modal. Below is my modal open scope:

```
$scope.addNewSchedule = function() {
      var dailog = $uibModal.open({
          templateUrl: 'app/partials/add-new-schedule.html',
          controller: addNewScheduleController,
          size: 'lg',
          scope: $scope
      });
    };
```

And of course, I have

```
<input ng-model="$parent.date5" datetime-picker date-format="dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm" />
```

in my add-new-schedule.html template, however, it not working. I'm sure I might just missout something simple and wish someone can advise me on this, many thanks~~~

Comment: Inspect the CSS of the date time picker in the modal, make sure the date picker  z-index , and other css vars like position and display are not hiding it

Comment: Thank you, Farzad Salimi Jazi. I added z-index: 1151 and it working fine now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a common problem with modal. As `z-index` of modal is higher tha `z-index` of datepicker. So, just inspect the code, find the class used by modal, datepicker and adjust the `z-index`.

Keep `z-index` of datepicker higher.

Comment: Thank you atulquest93. I added z-index : 1151 in my datepicker css, and it working fine now.